# Jenkinsfile: Multibranch + Pull request

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that is stored in Github repository root. I want to run tests whenever commit is made, and I want to test the whole build (running tests, creating a package and deploy to devel environment) when PR is created.

I managed to configure Github organization plugin, which sucessfully detects commits and PRs, but I don't know how to build PRs - when a PR is created, the commit is already "built" (Jenkinsfile is processed) so no additional action is triggered when a PR is created.

How can I tell Jenkis/Groovy to do the job for me?

Comment: did you check this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin ?

Comment: fortunately i was just blind. there is another tab in the organization folder, called "Pull requests". It's not very happy from UX side of view; most of my colleagues just did not notice this tab :) It's then simple in Jenkinsfile to decide which branch is being built by env.BRANCH_NAME.